# Shortcut to close all opened files in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a shortcut in IntelliJ IDEA to close all opened windows?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There is no shortcut in the default keymap, but you can assign it in Keymap settings for the **Close All** action.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Should anyone need screenshots: http://flummox-engineering.blogspot.com/2014/01/close-all-open-tabs-in-intellij_17.html

Answer (score 11):

You can also close all open files from 
Menu > Window > Editor tabs > Close all (or on mac: Command + F4)

Comment: I think on Mac: `command + F4` only closes the current file (tab)

Answer (score 8):

No default shortcut, but you can use the **Search Everywhere** shortcut to call it:

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + Type: `Close All` + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Alternatively:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> + Type: `Close All` + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

One more way just for fun:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> + Type: `Close All` + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

If you use VIM:

<kbd>ESC</kbd> <kbd>:qa</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

I did it in my Pycharm by adding a keyword shortcut:

1. Go to Settings by `ctrl+Alt+S`
2. Go to keymap where you can search (close all) and add your desire shortcut key for it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to set a shortcut in the keymap because it's not easy to come up with a simple shortcut that is not already taken, you can press Alt key and click X on the active tab. This will close all inactive tabs. Then you can click the X again to close the current tab. That way, all tabs will be closed without much effort.