# Close all tabs from all groups IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

I have an issue on IntelliJ where, when trying to close all tabs it just does not work as I expect it.

I have followed this to setup the [Close all shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11052292/shortcut-to-close-all-opened-files-in-intellij) this work if I only have a single group.

But in the case I have 2+ groups(assume multiple tabs on each group) it will only close the tabs on the ***active group***

```
___________
| 1  |  2 |
-----------
|    3    |
-----------
```

I notice that if I don't have any group(tab active) then all tabs in all groups will close. This is the case where file tree, console or something else not a tab is active.

***Active group***: parent group of the active tab.

I want to be able to hit my shortcut and close all tabs in all groups without moving out of a group.

Is this a bug or I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Request is welcome at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I have created a new issue thanks for the link: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-233693

Comment: Voted for the issue.